# Android AsyncTask .add code says cabbıt resolve

Tags: jsoup, parse-error

i couldnt find any code or resource of async task so i put it here. Sorry for that but how can i correct this code ?

```
    package com.example.tarko.deneme;

    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;

    import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
    import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
    import org.w3c.dom.Document;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Calendar;

    /**
    * Created by tarko on 25.08.2016.
    */
    public abstract class AsyncTask2 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>               {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
    super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params){
    try{


      Bundle lastPosts = null;
      lastPosts.clear();
      org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).get();

      //Ana Elementler
      Elements div_content_left = doc. select("div[id=conent-left]");
      Elements div_home_article = div_content_left.select("div[class=home-article");

      //Ara Başlıklar
      Elements div_article_title = div_home_article.select("div[class=article-title]");
      Elements div_article_content = div_home_article.select("div[class=article-content");
      Elements div_article_short = div_home_article.select("div[class=article-short]");

      //Son Elementler
      Elements images = div_article_content.select("img");
      Elements p = div_article_short.select("p");
      Elements h1 = div_article_title.select("h1");
      Elements a = h1.select("a");

      for (int i=0; i<a.size(); i++){
      lastPosts.add(new Post(a.get(i).text(),a.get(i).attr("href"),p.get(i).text()));
          resimAdresleri.add(images.get(i).attr("src"));
  }


    return null;
} catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }

    @Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values){
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}
@Override
protected void onCancelled(Void result){
    super.onCancelled(result);
}
}}
```

it goes error on .add samples it says cannot reslove method. Does the code changed ?

Comment: i think there is one "}" missing after `catch` statement.

Answer (score 0):

It errors because `Bundle` does not have a method called `add()`. Instead it has `Bundle.putString()`, `Bundle.putInt()` and etc.

Check the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) to see the best method for you.

Also, even if you get it to compile, it will fail at runtime because of this line of code:

```
Bundle lastPosts = null;
lastPosts.clear();
```

This will result in a `NullPointerException`, make sure you init your `Bundle` with:

```
Bundle lastPosts = new Bundle();
```